# Why am I getting an initialized Carrierwave uploader error when I migrate the database on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app with Carrierwave to Heroku.

When I run `heroku run rake db:migrate --app myapp` I get `rake aborted! uninitialized constant Activity::IconUploader`.

Activity is a model which contains

`mount_uploader :icon, IconUploader, :mount_on => :icon_file_name`

I have a file app/uploaders/icon_uploader.rb which contains

```
class IconUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  more or less default content
end
```

I have config/initializers/carrierwave.rb which defines fog credentials for storing files on Amazon S3 and sets the cache directory to tmp allow Carrerwave to work on Heroku.

The uploader works perfectly on my local dev environment.

Why am I getting this error on Heroku?

What steps can I take to trace the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibilities that I can come up with:

1. this file is not added to your git repository (but exists locally)
2. You need to add the code below to your autoload path
3. Something like this issue (https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/399)

Note, you shouldn't HAVE to do this:

**config/application.rb**

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/uploaders)
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse, you are correct. After posting this question, a number of other issues started cropping up. I eventually traced this some inconsistencies in my tracked files. Fixing the repo fixed this issue. Thanks